# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getUserInfomationByEmail

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I get the following error every morning.  I have to restart the server every morning to temporary fix the error. Probably, there may be a code related issue but why every morning? I assume there can be a server related issue too.

Here is the stack trace.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getUserInfomationByEmail
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at ws.AuthenticateStub.getUserInfomationByEmail(AuthenticateStub.java:226)
    at xxx.xxx.tvawsclient.authenticate.AuthClient.getUserInfomationByEmail(AuthClient.java:97)
    at controller.Auth.doGet(Auth.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

do you guys need any other information to help me?

Comment: why is this down voted?

Comment: "Why every morning?" -- probably the service is called on a schedule.  As for what the problem is, we couldn't even hazard a guess without some source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the porblem was mysql port goes idle after default time (8) hours when ther is no connection to the database. This was the reason to face this issue every morning.

There are two ways to handle this, 
1.using autoconnect=true property which is depricated.
2. Using connection pool

Following link gives more information.
[trouble shooting mysql connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html)

> 15.4: I have a servlet/application that works fine for a day, and then stops working overnight
>
> MySQL closes connections after 8 hours of inactivity. You either need
>   to use a connection pool that handles stale connections or use the
>   autoReconnect parameter (see Section 5.1, “Driver/Datasource Class
>   Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J”).
>
> Also, catch SQLExceptions in your application and deal with them,
>   rather than propagating them all the way until your application exits.
>   This is just good programming practice. MySQL Connector/J will set the
>   SQLState (see java.sql.SQLException.getSQLState() in your API docs) to
>   08S01 when it encounters network-connectivity issues during the
>   processing of a query. Attempt to reconnect to MySQL at this point.
>
> The following (simplistic) example shows what code that can handle
>   these exceptions might look like: